# proper way of using require.js

Tags: requirejs

```
//some.html
<script data-main="./Scripts/Main.js"  src="./Scripts/lib/require.js" ></script>
<script src="./Scripts/Multiply.js">

//Multiply.js
define('Main'.['jquery'], function($){
   $(document).ready(, function(){
      var sum = 1*1;
      $('#some').val(sum);
   })
}
```

Did I use require.js correctly? by adding each new external script(example Multiply.js), I will declare the new location in some.html, or it actually defeat the purpose of require.js? Any guideline will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add a script tag for each file you load. That is a job of requireJs. Proper way:

```
//some.html
<script data-main="./Scripts/Main.js"  src="./Scripts/lib/require.js" ></script>

// Main js should load multiply for you: 
define(['./Multiply'], function(multiply){
}

//Multiply.js
define(['jquery'], function($){
   $(document).ready( function(){
      var sum = 1*1;
      $('#some').val(sum);
   })
}
```

Comment: so I will define empty function at some.hmtl? With define on the each new js?

Comment: You will have a define in every file you use with requireJS. If you do not want to use that then you will have to use a shim : http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: I did use shim in my Main.js, it consist every common script that already predefine by other, like, jquery, jquery UI, backbone etc, thats y I stuck a bit, did I use the correct way to play with require.js? your guideline is helpful to me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`define` defines a module in RequireJS . Assuming you want `Mutliply.js` to be your actual program entry point, you need to use `require` instead of define.

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
   $(document).ready(, function(){
      var sum = 1*1;
      $('#some').val(sum);
   });
});
```

Here is [a nice tutorial on RequireJS](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/).

Comment: yeah, I did go through every single tutorial that can be found in google, but still, i dumb a bit on the proper way of using it, thanks for the link

Comment: @Se0ng11 this is a very good one that's not easy to find with google: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/